# object object with error handling in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

So I followed the error handling guide in the angular docs. I always seem to receive the error in my service, however, my console always displays my error object as '[object Object]'. Does anyone know what causes this and how I can fix this?

**My service file**

```
subViewPlus(section, sign){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/forum/subViewPlus/' + section + '/' + sign)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError)
    }

    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            console.error(
                `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
                `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an ErrorObservable with a user-facing error message
        return new ErrorObservable(
            'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
    };
```

**Screenshot that shows the logs to the console: how do I transform this [body body] into something more useful?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont do interpolation on the object. Instead do something like this.

```
console.error({
    "Backend returned code: ": error.status,
    "body was: ": error.error
})
```